# How to delete values of a wordpress post_meta_value

Tags: wordpress, update-post-meta

everyone

I would like to delete a value from the postmeta in my wordpress installation - and not a complete metavalue, but only part of the content in it.

e.g. metakey = test
metavalue = abba; dancing; queen;

and the "dancing" should be thrown out.
With update_post_meta and delete_post_meta I only manage to delete the complete metavalue or metakey.
update_post_meta( $id, 'test', $dancing);
delete_post_meta( $id, 'test', $dancing);
dont work :-(

how can i remove only part of it?

lg
yeah

Answer (score 0):

I think it works.
First I get the value of the previous postmeta.
Then we change it and finally save it in our post.
The order is as follows:

```
$test_meta_key = get_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_key');

$test_meta_key = str_replace('dancing', '', $test_meta_key);

update_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_key', $test_meta_key);
```

Comment: Hi Morteza,   thank you for your comment.  I thought that update_post_meta would automatically serialize the value, so that the original values ​​would no longer be in the postmeta if I remove it with str_replace & then save it with update_post_meta?

i have read it here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290189/inserting-serialized-value-into-wp-postmeta-using-update-post-meta

or am I misunderstanding something?


kind regars
Jo

Comment: hi @JSt. you're welcome
I saw exactly the same behavior in that link.
So for you, the update_post_meta function should automatically update the total value of a key, regardless of what the previous value was.
So we need to first take the previous value and then change it and save it in the new value.
What I saw in that link was that
In their meta, the value was stored as an array, so they resent the value as a presentation to update_post_meta.
We do the same in this.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the dancing word from the desired metavalue. You don't have to serialize if meta value is an array, wordpress will automatically do it for you.

```
$post_id    = 1;
$metakey    = 'test'; 
$metavalue  = "abba; dancing; queen";
$metavalue  = "abba; queen"; // updated meta value
update_post_meta( $post_id, $metakey, $metavalue );
```

if $metavalue is array

```
$metavalue = [ "abba", "dancing", "queen" ];
$metavalue = [ "abba", "queen" ]; // updated meta value
update_post_meta( $post_id, $metakey, $metavalue );
```